# List running processes with CPU and network usage in command line

Tags: windows, command-line

How do I find the list (only prints each time called) of running processes with its CPU usage, and network usage in command line on Windows?

I know `tasklist.exe` but that doesn't have CPU/network usage.

Any command line tools online that can do this? Preferably those which can also sort according to CPU/network usage.

Comment: what I want is like perfmon , but running in CLI

Answer (score 4):

"typeperf" is your man. Try typeperf /? for the usage. It gives all the counters that are available in perfmon on the command line.

Comment: I tried the /? flag.. but it doesn't make sense.. can you for eg, give the required lines for showing processes with CPU usage and its network usage?

Answer (score 1):

You can try out [PsList](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896682) utility from SysInternals (acquired by Microsoft now), although it doesn't display network usage.